# How can I list all toplevels in Tcl/Tk, including those created via wm manage?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I've recently discovered the highly useful `wm manage` command, that takes an existing tk frame anywhere in the hierarchy, and promotes it to a new toplevel widget. It's useful for tearing off pieces of an existing single window application and making independent tool palettes etc.

I now find myself wanting to list all the toplevels in the app, since there are now many more than the original main window.

The result of `winfo children .` gives all the toplevels that are children of the root window, however all the torn off ones retain their path in the hierarchy and are therefore not listed. Is there another way to list all the tk window names that are toplevels that will include these torn off frames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go through all the widgets hierarchy and collect widgets for which `[winfo toplevel]` equals the widget itself, like with the following proc:

```
proc toplevels {{w .}} {
    if {[winfo toplevel $w] eq $w} {
        set res [list $w]
    } else {
        set res {}
    }
    foreach ww [winfo children $w] {
        lappend res {*}[toplevels $ww]
    }
    return $res
}
```

Comment: That does the trick, but I realise now that the app in question has a lot of menu widgets, which are not usually mapped, but show up in the list of toplevels. I've filtered these out with `winfo viewable $w` and that gives me a reliable list of the toplevels currently shown on screen. Is that a sensible way to tell apart menus from other toplevels (I want the ones with window decoration/titlebars etc). It might cause problems if a menu happens to be open when this is run?

Comment: You may consult `[winfo class $w]` which equals `Menu` for menu items.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need the toplevels currently shown on the screen, the `wm stackorder .` command should do the trick.